# How to incorporate autocomplete mode in c# combobox having combobox style as dropdown list?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, autocomplete

I have a combobox in c# and i want to include auto complete feature into it. I cannot change the `DropDownStyle` to anything but `DropDownList` mode. 
But when i am changing the following properties it gives me an exception.

`symbol1_textbox.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
 symbol1_textbox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
 symbol1_textbox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;`

NotSupportedException

Only the value AutoCompleteMode.None can be used when DropDownStyle is ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList and AutoCompleteSource is not AutoCompleteSource.ListItems.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `AutoCompleteSource` and `ComboBoxStyle` before setting `AutocompleteMode`. Which means order matters.

```
cmb.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
cmb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
cmb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;            
cmb.DataSource = nameList;
```

Answer (score 0):

just do what the exception is telling you:

```
 symbol1_textbox.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
 symbol1_textbox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend; 
 symbol1_textbox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems; 
 symbol1_textbox.DataSource = symbol1_list;
```

and then populate the "Items" with all Items you need

Comment: how can i populate AutoCompleteList? my combobox datasource is already populated with a list of strings

Comment: then setting the  AutoCompleteSource to ListItems is all what you need.

Comment: `symbol1_textbox.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
 symbol1_textbox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
 symbol1_textbox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
symbol1_textbox.DataSource = symbol1_list;`

in this order?

Comment: it is still giving me the same exception @
`symbol1_textbox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend; `

Comment: i tried that in my code, and it works perfectly fine for me. Have you made sure to  change  AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource; to AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;

Comment: I have set the property values from UI Designer and it works now. Thanks @Alexis Peters

Answer (score 0):

It should be -

```
comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
comboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```